# Как в MS SQL в результат первого запроса добавить значения из результата второго запроса в зависимости от значения каждой строки первого запроса

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица с задачами dbo.tasks (id, name)

`SELECT * FROM dbo.tasks;`

[image: dbo.tasks]

У задач есть зависимые (предыдущие) задачи из таблицы dbo.depend (в столбце succ_id указан id последующей задачи из таблицы dbo.tasks)

`SELECT * FROM dbo.depend;`

[image: dbo.depend]

Необходимо вывести в результате таблицу с задачами и в дополнительной колонке количество зависимых (предыдущих) работ

Для конкретной задачи я делаю так

```
DECLARE @count_pred INT, @task_id INT = 111;
--Получаем количество зависимых (предыдущих) задач для конкретной задачи
SELECT @count_pred = COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.tasks a, dbo.depend b
WHERE a.id = b.id AND b.succ_id = @task_id;
--PRINT @count_pred;
--Объеденяем и показываем результат
SELECT a.id, a.name, COUNT(b.id) count_pred
FROM dbo.tasks a
JOIN dbo.depend b ON a.id = b.succ_id AND a.id = @task_id
GROUP BY a.id, a.name;
```

[image: res]

Но как мне вывести количество зависимых (предыдущих) задач для каждой строки результата запроса, чтобы получился такой результат:

[image: res_true]

UPD:

```
USE [database]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tasks](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[depend](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [succ_id] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tasks] ([id],[name])
VALUES
(1,'Купить краску'),
(11,'Подготовить стену'),
(111,'Покраска стены'),
(2,'Купить лопаты'),
(222,'Земляные работы'),
(3,'Купить трубы'),
(333,'Трубопровод');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[depend] ([id],[succ_id])
VALUES
(1,111),
(11,111),
(2,222),
(3,333);
GO
```

Comment: А чем не подходит
`
SELECT a.id, a.name, COUNT(b.id) count_pred
FROM dbo.tasks a
JOIN dbo.depend b ON a.id = b.succ_id
GROUP BY a.id, a.name;
`

Comment: Дело в том, что может быть ситуация когда зависимых (предыдущих) задач нет и такие строки не попадают в результат запроса. Поэтому я в начале считал количество зависимых работ и пытался выводить по условию `IF @count_pred > 0 ...`, но понял что это не совсем подходящая идея

Comment: Никаких проблем, LEFT OUTER JOIN решает: `SELECT a.id, a.name, COUNT(b.id) count_pred FROM dbo.tasks a LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.depend b ON a.id = b.succ_id GROUP BY a.id, a.name`

Comment: Не совсем то что нужно, LEFT OUTER JOIN выводит все записи из таблицы dbo.tasks. Мне же необходимо получать каким-то образом последнюю из зависимых задачу, искать для нее все предыдущие и проставлять количество, если их нет, то 0

Comment: Это уже рекурсивный запрос надо делать. Посмотрите синтаксис и примеры для MS SQL